# Android splitting string based on special characters

Tags: java, android

Currently I am trying to get an embedded URL from a RSS feed. Thus the initial URL has special characters like the following:

[http://www.facebook.com/1.php?&...http://www.example.com...&"](http://www.facebook.com/1.php?&...http://www.example.com...&%22)

I am using `String.split(expression)` function to split and get the http://www.example.com

But for special expressions like "?", I am not able to split the string.

Is there any other way to split strings based on special characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String.split expects a parameter which is a regular expression. Since `?` is a special character in regular expressions, to do what you want, you'd actually write it as:

```
myStr.split("\\?");
```

And thus it recognizes it as the character `?`, and not as a special regex character.

Note that two backslashes are needed. The regular expression itself is `"\?"`, but since to put `"\"` in a java string we need to write it as `"\\"`, the expression string thus becomes `"\\?"`.

To learn more about regular expressions, I recommend you to check [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a uri and conforms to standard URI semantics. Therefore you can use one of the standard Uri representations in Android to do the heavy lifting for you. Your Uri contains a query string which follows the main part of the Uri after the `?` character and is comprised of a number of key / value pairs separated by `&` characters. You simply need to parse your Uri in to an `ndroid.net.Uri` object and then call `getQueryParameter(String paramName)` to get your required query param:

```
String raw = "http://www.mydomain.com/index.html?param1=hello&param2=world&param3=test";
Uri uri = Uri.parse( raw );
String param = uri.getQueryParameter( "param2" );
```

This will return "world" in `param`.