# How to split double double inside String

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I want to get two double for Google Map. `"lonLat": "-128.1048,51.083",`

```
String lonlat = location.getLonLat();
Double d = Double.parseDouble(lonlat);
.position(new LatLng(double, double)) // Google Map
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android splitting string based on special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255917/android-splitting-string-based-on-special-characters)

Comment: Why just split it by ",".

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
String CurrentString = "-128.1048,51.083",
String[] separated = CurrentString.split(",");
separated[0]; // 
separated[1];
```